# How to link my hosted domain to Elastic Load Balancer and Route 53 in Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I have a domain in GoDaddy. 
I am having two instances configured with Elastic Load Balancing (ELB) for traffic handling, it just give me the public DNS name.

---

I need to configure ELB DNS name(xxxxxxx.yyyyyy-elb.amazonaws.com) to Route 53 and with my Godaddy domain name(exmaple.com).

Can you please give me step by step procedure ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you created a Route53 Zone - you would be given 4 - Domains URLs. You need to take those and put that in the place of Name Servers in your GoDaddy Account.

This Link [Setting up GoDaddy and Route53](http://blog.vizuri.com/setting-up-godaddy-and-route53-with-ghost-blogger) would help you with detailed walk though.

Comment: @NavinLeon : Thanks. I have fixed the correct URL

Comment: Thanks Brother. Your solution is working like a charm :-)